# Webkit.Галерея на чистом css

Tags: html, css3, webkit

Здравствуйте,  сделал галерею при наведении мышкой картинка должна увеличиваться

```
.gallery img{
-webkit-transform:scale(0.8); 
-moz-transform:scale(0.8); 
-o-transform:scale(0.8); 
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
opacity: 0.7; 
margin: 0 10px 5px 0; 
}

.gallery img:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1); 
-moz-transform:scale(1.1); 
-o-transform:scale(1.1); 
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
opacity: 1;

}
```

но на странице уменьшенные элементы когда на них не наводишь находятся на расстоянии как-будто они в полном размере.Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы пока я не навел на картинку они на сайте распологались друг под дружкой

Comment: Префиксы не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте пункт без префикса.(Предыдущие не удаляйте!) -

**transform:scale(0.8);
transtition-duration:0.5s; и transform:scale(1.1);**

*Итого:*

```
.gallery img{
-webkit-transform:scale(0.8); 
-moz-transform:scale(0.8); 
-o-transform:scale(0.8); 
transform:scale(0.8);
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
transition-duration:0.5s
opacity: 0.7; 
margin: 0 10px 5px 0; 
}

.gallery img:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1); 
-moz-transform:scale(1.1); 
-o-transform:scale(1.1); 
transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
opacity: 1;

}
```

> Если не сработает, добавьте просто в начале `position:relative;`

Comment: Вопрос не об этом. Размеры, отводимые под картинки идут под 100%, при уменьшении маштаба до 80% остаётся 20% размера на пустое пространство. Он спрашивает, как его убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Отображать без наведения элементы в полном размере.

Либо обеспечивать их размеры другими средствами при помощи css.

Comment: неужели никак таким способом нельзя?А какими другими средствами можно?

Comment: @ламер, отрицательные margin'ы, например.